# Porting C++ code to Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, c++, silverlight, porting

I have C++ application which has UI developed using MFC, does some networking using sockets (using boost libraries) and some image processing. I want to move this application into Silvelight framework (I can use 4.0 if required) so that it can be used over the internet easily. Here I want to move all parts (UI + networking etc) in to C# but keep the image processing code in unmanaged C++ only. I don't know .NET framework yet, but whatever I have read so far suggests that it is not possible to call the unmanaged code from a silvelight web application. Is my understanding correct? Can something be done to achieve what I am trying to do? Also, if somebody has some suggestions on how to go about porting the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Silverlight 4 supports COM when running in trusted mode.

So, tecnically you could have Silverlight call your c++ library using COM. 
The main problem I see is on deployment and I don't think it's a good idea.
Also, remember that Silverlight can run on Macs but COM is Windows only.
What you could do is to have the image processing happening on the server, but then you
can run into scalability issues. 
Transfering large amounts of data between client and server can become an issue.
UI response should probably be closely evaluated too.
Regarding porting the code, well, you are most certain looking at a complete rewrite.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I don't want to go through the complexities of COM for doing this. In such a case, if WPF ClickOnce is a good alternative?

Comment: @Asha: It is probably a better fit.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using WPF instead of Silverlight if possible.  With WPF you'd be able to reuse your C++ as is because desktop .NET / unmanaged interop is very good (P/Invoke or CLI/C++).

Otherwise you are stuck porting your C++ to managed code, which could prove to be laborious and the resulting code inefficient.